# Connecting Eclipse to MySQL Database in java

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, command-prompt

How to connect Eclipse to MySQL command prompt made database?
I am using Eclipse program for java programming and i need to connect to database i have used command prompt to create database and add tables and figures into it but i searched all over internet and can't find a way to connect to it.

I have tried using the connection via folder as well as the default one that found on tutorials...

Anyone knows possible way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)